# Is there a way to centraly manage multiple Cisco ASAs?

Tags: cisco-asa

I work with many different clients that have multiple ASAs each. I was wondering if there was a way to centraly manage these ASAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco Security Manager: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6498/index.html

Comment: Ha, I thought that was discontinued for some reason. Thanks, I'll check it out. I'll leave this open for a bit longer to see if there is anything else out there.